# перевод из char[] в string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть строка

```
char buff[1024]; //1024
bsize = 3 // зависит от строки
```

Получает данные, в конец строки добавляю 0

```
// добавление завершающего нуля
        buff[bsize] = 0;
```

Перевожу строку в `string`

```
string name = buff; // результат "hi"
```

Есть еще один `string`

```
String test = "hi";
```

Возникает вопрос почему, результат false? Если должно быть true

```
if(name == test) // Результат false
```

Comment: Чему равно магическое число `bsize`?

Comment: У меня все работает. Попробуйте, разве что `'\0'` вместо `0`. Либо у вас перевод строки в `buf` попадает.

Comment: andy, добавил. Но не помогло. Хотя когда я вывожу строку в консоль, то значение индетичное

Comment: а может быть `String` и `string` - разные классы? тогда все может быть.

Comment: нет, везде использую string

Comment: @Ewrei_228 единственное, что может быть, непечатаемые символы в `buf` (`'\r'`, `'\n'` или что-то подобное). Сравните `name.size() == test.size()`

Comment: решил проверить на size. Они различаются, у name(size) = 3, test(size) = 2. Может в этом дело?

Comment: @Ewrei_228 Конечно, именно в этом и дело. Выводите ASCII коды символов в name и смотрите, что у Вас там лишнего. `for (char x : name) cout << int(x) << endl;`

Comment: спасибо, разобрался. Если сделаете как ответ, принял бы как решением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, в строку `name` попадают "непечатные" символы (типа `\n`, `\r`)
Проверьте равенство размеров строк (`name.size() == test.size()`) и если они не совпадают, выведите коды символов в строке name:

```
for (char x : name)
   cout << int(x) << endl;
```